# Can the Mage Wars Warlock be played without any Demon cards?

Tags: deck-building, mage-wars

As the subject states, I was wondering if the Mage Wars Core Set comes with enough Fire type cards to allow the Warlock Mage to build a spellbook with absolutely no Demon cards. Without seeing the cards, I will assume that most, if not all of the other Dark magic cards are OK, but I would ultimately prefer a pure Fire Magic spellbook.

So as to preemptively answer the almost inevitable 'Why?', I will simply say that, as an orthodox Christian, my conscience doesn't allow me to play a game with such cards. I would prefer not to debate/explain this further, as I believe such a discussion is well beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: What about other dark creature that warlock can use? Like skeletons, vampires and werewolfs? Could you use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the starting Core Set I would have to say that it would be a very tough if not an impossible feat to be able to play the Warlock without the Demon cards, as there is only one Flame type creature, but it just happens to also be a Demon.  So you would have to spend quite a bit of your deck points on the doubled points from creatures not being a dark or fire type.

This may be doable, as you may be able to counter balance with some of the powerful Flame attack spells that can really do some damage, especially when combined with an equipment called Elemental Wand, to allow you to bind and recast the attack spells each turn.

Comment: Do you have to have creatures and/or is it greatly detrimental to not have creatures?

Comment: It is greatly detrimental to not have creatures, as then your opponent gets many extra action phases that you don't. So you spend your whole turn trying to deal with what he put on the field, and he can just cast more spells to either attack you, build up his creature base, or just gain mana to cast a big creature that it takes you multiple turns to deal with. So then while you are dealing with that creature, he can just destroy you. So if you had some little dummy blocker creatures in the way, it may help a little bit. But I would recommend having a balance of the types of possible card types

Comment: In one game, I was trying to set things up to trap my opponent that I forgot about creatures, and he just overran me with creatures. It didn't even end up being very close of a game, even if the damage scale made it look like it.

Answer (score -1):

Google "mage wars Warlock strategy" one of the results will be a 4 minute youtube video of a Warlock tearing a beastmaster apart, winning the game in 9 rounds, without summoning a single creature, demons or otherwise.

Comment: seems like this should be more a comment than a complete answer. It doesn't go into any details and the youtube link could become invalid at which point this post has no real information.